# (JavaFX)(FXML) Does anyone know how I can make the background of a ScrollPane completely transparent?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

all I'm looking for is to make the background of my scroll pane completely transparent so you can see all the way through it while keeping the children i.e. Images and labels and others things visible. I've tried doing -fx-background and -fx-background-color but those don't yield the view I want, any solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've figured it out, I was really dumb, as most situations in coding end up being, as I stated in my question I tried those two CSS lines of code, however I neglected to try them at the same time. Now that I have, I've gotten the result I was looking for. If anyone else has this issue in the future:

-fx-background and -fx-background-color are for two different parts of the ScrollPane, use them in unison and set then both to transparent.